# MySQL - Joins and Subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I'm looking a question that asks 'List for each year the name of the worst film(s) released that year. Films are rated by score: the lower the score, the worse the film. In the event of a tie, all tied films should be listed. The results should appear chronologically.'

The tables are:

```
movies(id, title, yr, score, votes, director)
castings(movieid, actorid)
actors(id, name)
```

So far I've gotten:

```
SELECT m.title
FROM movies AS m
WHERE m.score = (SELECT MIN(score) FROM movies)
ORDER BY m.yr DESC
```

Comment: Please share sample input data and the expected output for that data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. As it is, your query gives you the movie with the worst score overall all years. You need to *correlate* the subquery with the outer query:

```
select yr, title
from movies m
where score = (select min(score) from movies m1 where m1.year = m.year)
order by yr desc
```

You can get the same results with by joining the table with an aggregate subquery:

```
select m.yr, m.title
from movies m
inner join (select yr, min(score) score from movies group by yr) x
    on x.yr = m.yr and x.score = m.score
```